# Using Emoji in Haskell

Tags: haskell, twitter, ghc

I've recently come across a bot on Twitter named [EmojiHaskell](https://twitter.com/EmojiHaskell), that claims to tweet 'interpretable Haskell code with emoji variable names'. A particular [Tweet](https://twitter.com/EmojiHaskell/status/631416105307869184) caught my attention, as it looked like malformed syntax to me, so I decided to take a closer look. So far I've produced the following code:

```
module Main where

 :: [] -> Maybe 
 [] = Nothing
 (:as) = Just 

main = print $  "♥"
```

Since I've used `λ` on occasion in my Haskell code, I expected this code to work, but it appears that GHC doesn't like the emoji at all.

With `$ runhaskell Main.hs` I get:

> Main.hs:4:1: parse error on input ‘’

I've already had a look at the [UnicodeSyntax](https://wiki.haskell.org/Unicode-symbols) extension,
and tried to only use some or single emoji instead of all of them to see if a certain one provokes the problem.

Now my question is this:
Is there currently a Haskell compiler that would accept the code?
Can I get GHC to work with this code somehow?

Comment: I don't know if you care that much but you could make a preprocessor. Afaik GHC has a flag to run a custom preprocessor of your choosing.

Comment: AFAIK, Unicode Syntax allows you to replace `->` with `→`, and so on. It is *not* required just to use Unicode characters in your source code. https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#unicode-syntax

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That code is not valid haskell. The reason is that  (like, probably, all Emojis) is a symbol character:

```
Prelude> import Data.Char
Prelude Data.Char> generalCategory ''
OtherSymbol
```

But you can still use them like any other symbol, namely as an operator:

```
Prelude Data.Char> let () = (+)
Prelude Data.Char> 32  42
74
```

Furthermore, as user3237465 pointed out, if you use the prefix syntax for operators, i.e. put it in parentheses, you can even use it like any other symbol:

```
() :: [a] -> Maybe a
() [] = Nothing
() (():as) = Just ()

main = print $ () "♥"
```

This is almost the example in the original post. Unfortunately, this trick does not work for the type variable. The [the documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#infix-tycons) is worded a bit unfortunately, but [in fact](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10772#comment:2) symbols are never type variables and always type constructors

Comment: Operators don't have to be infix, so this is legal: `() [] = Nothing; () (():as) = Just (); main = print $ () "a"`.

Comment: Thanks. I wrongly assumed that `()` would force it to have a function type accepting two arguments, but that is only the case for operator sections, it seems. Bug [#10772](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10772) filed about the it not working on the type level.

Comment: Ah, very cool to see the update after the hint from user3237465 :)